# Use linq to return a selection of data from list<t>

Tags: c#, linq, ienumerable

I have the following code:

```
public class UserList
    {
        public string UName { get; set; }
        public string Auth { get; set; }
        public Boolean PUser { get; set; }
    }


    class DeveloperPreview
    {
        List<UserList> UserList = new List<UserList>();
        public void PopulateUsers()
        {
            UserList.Add(new UserList() { UName="Daryl",Auth="12345",PUser=true});
            UserList.Add(new UserList() { UName = "Test", Auth = "239", PUser = false });
            UserList.Add(new UserList() { UName="Developer",Auth="2",PUser=true});

        }

        public string Authenticateuser(string Username, string Auth)
        {
            var User = UserList.Where((t => t.UName.Contains(Username)));
            return User.UName;
        }

    }
```

which is being invoked by:

```
    DeveloperPreview Dev = new DeveloperPreview();
    private void SubmitClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        Dev.PopulateUsers();
        string Auth = Dev.Authenticateuser("Daryl","2");
        MessageBox.Show(Auth);
    }
```

I'm having trouble returning only the rows in the list which contains "Daryl"

I have used this as a reference: [C# LINQ select from list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3117003/c-sharp-linq-select-from-list)

But am still having some-what difficulty on how to actually perform this task, I later wish to manipulate/work with the data gathered from the list, but that's another bridge that will be built when necessary

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is in following lines:

```
 var User = UserList.Where((t => t.UName.Contains(Username)));
 return User.UName;
```

`Enumerable.Where` will return an `IEnumerable<T>`, which is a collection of records not a single record. So later when you try to access `User.UName` then you will get an error. You need to select a single record. You can use [First](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb291976(v=vs.100).aspx) / [FirstOrDefault](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb340482.aspx) / [Single](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.single.aspx) / [SingleOrDefault](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.singleordefault.aspx) based on your requirement. Your method could be:

```
public string Authenticateuser(string Username, string Auth)
{
    var User = UserList.FirstOrDefault(t => t.UName.Contains(Username));
    if(User != null)    
       return User.UName;
    else  //user not found
       return null;//throw exception / Message etc
}
```

Read about: [LINQ Single vs SingleOrDefault vs First vs FirstOrDefault](http://www.technicaloverload.com/linq-single-vs-singleordefault-vs-first-vs-firstordefault/)

Comment: So, just for a little further understanding (extremely vague understanding in linq), what's happening here is that it's essentially a select query going on here, to return the first result set in the same `list<t>` data type, but this list will be *filtered* to only element as opposed to the original list, which contains 3 elements?

Comment: @DarylGill, Yes. With your original expression using `Where` you will get back a `IEnumerable<UserList>` but with just one item in it *(since that will only match the criteria)*. With `FirstOrDefault`  you will get the first item matching your criteria or *null* if none is found.

Comment: @DarylGill, one more thing to add, you can add `First/FirstOrDefault` at the end of your expression like: `var User = UserList.Where((t => t.UName.Contains(Username))).FirstOrDefault();`, but since `FirstOrDefault` can also take a condition I have used that in my code.

Comment: Just a little update if your interested. Had complications returning the list, so I've modified `var User = UserList.Where(t => t.UName == Username).ToList();` and is being manipulated back on main screen as: `Auth.FirstOrDefault().UName`

Answer (score 1):

I think all you really need to do is change this:

```
var User = UserList.Where((t => t.UName.Contains(Username)));
```

to this:

```
var User = UserList.Where((t => t.UName.Contains(Username))).FirstOrDefault();
```

The Where statement returns an IEnumerable, you need the first result from that IEnumerable.

Comment: fyi you can skip the `Where` call - like most LINQ extension methods, `FirstOrDefault` will accept the predicate clause directly.

Comment: true, but I wanted keep his code mostly intact so it would be easier for the OP to understand :)

Answer (score 1):

This:

```
var User = UserList.Where((t => t.UName.Contains(Username)));
```

Returns an `IEnumerable<T>`, not a single item. What you probably want is:

```
var User = UserList.Where((t => t.UName.Contains(Username))).FirstOrDefault();
```

This will return the first matching item (or null if none is found).

Answer (score 1):

You could use:

```
var User = UserList.Where(t => t.UName == Username).FirstOrDefault();
```

I don't know if it will cause issues, but having property names matching object names could get quite confusing.  You're using "UserList" to represent a List of UserList objects.

I would think this would make more sense:

```
public class User
{
    public string UName { get; set; }
    public string Auth { get; set; }
    public Boolean PUser { get; set; }
}

class DeveloperPreview
{
    List<User> UserList = new List<User>();
    public void PopulateUsers()
    {
        UserList.Add(new User() { UName="Daryl",Auth="12345",PUser=true});
        UserList.Add(new User() { UName = "Test", Auth = "239", PUser = false });
        UserList.Add(new User() { UName="Developer",Auth="2",PUser=true});

    }

    public string Authenticateuser(string Username, string Auth)
    {
        var user = UserList.Where(t => t.UName == Username).FirstOrDefault();
        return user.UName;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

What's happening here is that [.Where](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb549418(v=vs.100).aspx) is narrowing down the list, but will always return an IEnumerable<>, even if that enumerable only contains one element. If you want to return a single row, you need to add a call to one of the following methods

- [.First()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb291976(v=vs.100).aspx) returns the first element, Errors if there is no first element
- [.FirstOrDefault()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb340482(v=vs.100).aspx) returns the first element, or null if there are none
- [.Single()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb155325(v=vs.100).aspx) Returns the single object, or errors if there isn't exactly one object
- [.SingleOrDefault()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb342451(v=vs.100).aspx) Returns the single object, null if there is none, and errors if there is more than one

Note that all but these extension methods return IEnumerable so that you can chain calls to them, such as

```
UserList
    .Where( t => t.UName.Contains(Username) )
    .Select( t => t.UName )
    .DefaultIfEmpty(string.Empty)
    .First();
```